# Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade froze

Tags: boot, 16.04, upgrade, accounts

While doing the upgrade to 16.04 it basically stopped halfway.  Left the PC for over 12 hours to make certain but the status bar did not move.  Did a hard stop and tried a reboot.  Now it is asking for my user name and password and the only one I always use is my Ubuntu one account.  I have tried several times and it will not accept it.  Not sure what to do now.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to boot with a usb live system or CD live system to check the state of the system. It depends how the system is installed (native devices or LVM volumes ? Crypted devices ?). If you can handle the different options you could try to mount the system inside the live session and check if your user is still existing. you can change the root and user password with:

```
chroot /mount-point-of-you-system
passwd root...
passwd user....
```

After a reboot your login should work. But there might be more that this hint alone is not working...

Comment: I am still wondering how many people patch / update there system without a fall-back (image backup). Hm...